# What software can I use to make it easy for developers on my project to vote?

Tags: software-development, open-source

I am working on an open source project, and we are looking to make changes to the way we do version control.

I want to propose several systems, and have the developers vote.

What would be a good platform for doing this, where the developers would not need to create an account to vote on something...

EDIT: Does anyone know of a system that either implements with GitHub or Google login, or allows me to block repeat IP ranges, refreshes, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I could have phrased it better.

Comment: Regardless of the approach used for such decisions, I'd strongly suggest to ensure there's a clear (i.e. documented) view on the options, pros and cons. This is very useful to avoid the same discussion two years after the change. :)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest that, rather than voting, you work with your developers (or just senior developers if the team is too large) to get a consensus on how to amend the way you do version control. The reasons for this are (in no particular order):

1. The rest of the team may have good suggestions that you haven't come up with.
2. Voting tends to be a win-lose situation, and if you have more than one alternative likely more than half of the team isn't going to be in favor of the solution chosen.
3. Voting isn't necessarily going to reflect serious thought on the part of the voter.

Remember that your developers are key stakeholders, just like your customers. In fact, if you look at changing the version control system as a project in and of itself, they **are** the customers. Engaging them in a discussion and achieving a consensus on why changing the version control system is beneficial, precisely what should be changed, how it should look at the end etc is IMHO better than presenting them with a short-list of alternatives.

Comment: Thank you Doug for this insight, any thoughts on a non-binding private vote? Or putting a "This vote is purely to obtain popular opinion" in red letters?

Comment: I think that asking for feedback on the different options is better than asking for them to "vote". You would still get an idea of where everyone stands, identify pros and cons for different options that you might not have considered etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are all on the same Exchange server, just use the Outlook voting options.  Otherwise, something like Google Forms would be a great idea.

Comment: Most of the developers would scoff at using outlook / Microsoft products =P. Some of them are linux kernal devs iirc... I will check out Google forms though, thanks!

Comment: This link may provide you some additional detail: http://www.demogeek.com/2009/04/01/polls-made-easier-with-google-docs-spreadsheet/

Answer (score 2):

I would:

1. Do a **Brainstorming & Painstorming** meeting to gather the requirements and problems
2. **Do a research** and find possible solutions
3. **Make a presentation** to share a research results with the others
4. **Do a survey** / voting

And for activity #4 I would suggest [SurveyMonkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com/). I use it in similiar situations and it also has a "Other/please specify" option (in case you really do not want to stick to researched solutions only).

Answer (score 1):

If you consider something long term as well, I would propose two options, both open source:

- http://drupal.org/project/ideatorrent (example -
  http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/) - haven't
  tried it, but it's worth considering for its simplicity. Slightly like Dell's IdeaStorm
  (http://www.ideastorm.com/).
- http://www.limesurvey.org/ - a different animal as this is primarily a survey platform, but it certainly has the measures you'd mentioned. A very useful thing - seen it work with surveys of 1K respondents and more.

Another thing you can consider is checking with CMS/wiki software. Perhaps you have something already. I'm sure about Joomla (easy survey module), and I'd be astonished, if Drupal didn't have an add-on for that too.

Answer (score 0):

You never get the best answer by voting. Because not all your developers are experts in version control systems. It is better to get a group of the most competent developers and let them achieve a consensus. No software is required for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two voting solutions that I like:

- [Trello](http://www.trello.com) (created by founders of Stack Overflow) - allows users to vote items up and down
- [Google Moderator](https://www.google.com/moderator/)

Answer (score 0):

Another long-term solution is http://www.osqa.net It satisfies all your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developers of [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com).

With our tool you can quickly prioritize tasks or find decisions with the least rejection (or highest acceptance).

Users can vote without account or can login with their google account.

Here are two examples (Dot Voting and Systemic Consensus):

[image]
[image]